# Formspree ajax with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using React to build a static website. I'm trying to figure out how to use formspree using Javascript ES6 & promises.

This is the form markup:

```
<form method="POST" action={email}>
            <Label>Name:</Label>
            <Input name="name" />
            <Label>Email:</Label>
            <Input type="email" name="email" />
            <Label>Message:</Label>
            <Textarea name="message" />
            <Input type="text" name="_gotcha" style={gotcha}/>
            <Button onClick={this.formSubmit} buttonStyle="isOutlined" color="isWarning">Submit</Button>
          </form>
```

and the `formSubmit` method:

```
  formSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('form submit button');
  }
```

This is formsprees example using jQuery, but I'd rather get used to es6 and promises.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://formspree.io/you@email.com", 
    method: "POST",
    data: {message: "hello!"},
    dataType: "json"
});
```